# Bottle route to handle POST and GET

Tags: python, post, get, wsgi, bottle

In my webapp code I keep having constructs like this:

```
@app.route('some_method/<data>', method=['GET'], name='some_method')
def view(id):
    data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)

    ...

@app.route('some_method', method=['POST'], name='some_method')
def view():
    data = request.files.values()[0].file.read() if len(request.files) else request.body.read()

    ...
```

Where `...` is the same code for both `view` functions. This is not very DRY. Is there any established good practice to handle both POST and GET in bottle app efficiently?

Comment: Why not just use a function for the common code?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way that comes to mind is to put "…" into it's own method/function and just call it

```
def process_stuff(data):
   . . .

@app.route('some_method/<data>', method=['GET'], name='some_method')
def view(id):
    data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)
    process_stuff(data)

@app.route('some_method', method=['POST'], name='some_method')
def view():
    data = request.files.values()[0].file.read() if len(request.files) else request.body.read()
    process_stuff(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

My approche would be:

```
@app.route('some_method', method=['GET', 'POST'], name='some_method')
@app.route('some_method/<id>', method=['GET', 'POST'], name='some_method')
def view(id=None):
    if id and request.method == 'POST':
        data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        data = request.files.values()[0].file.read() if len(request.files) else request.body.read()
    else
        pass # handle this 404 error

    ...
```